# for loop for increment values

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to obtain a dataset with all possible pairs combinations of values of a and b.
a : from 0 to 30 (31 values)
b : from 0 to 30 (31 values)

My problem is that with the code below, I obtain all the pairs of possible values but it excludes the 0 values. d1 length is 900 (30x30) instead of 961 (31x31)

```
a<- numeric()
b <- numeric()

for (i in 0:30) {
  for (j in 0:30) {
    a[i]<-i
    b[j]<-j
    d1 <- expand.grid(y = a, x = b)
     }
}
```

the correct r code to solve my problem

Comment: R is not zero-indexed.  `a[i]` where `i == 0` is a nonexistant location so the value is not stored.  also, to get a vector of the values 0 to 30 you don't need to make a vector and assign a value to each slot - just type `0:30`.  try `expand.grid(y = 0:30, x = 0:30)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to preallocate vectors `a` and `b` then fill them, the structure `0:30` creates a vector containing the integers 0 to 30.

You can just use:

```
d1 <- expand.grid(0:30, 0:30)
```

Which gives you the expected 961 ranks:

```
> str(d1)
'data.frame':   961 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Var1: int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ Var2: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "out.attrs")=List of 2
  ..$ dim     : int [1:2] 31 31
  ..$ dimnames:List of 2
  .. ..$ Var1: chr [1:31] "Var1= 0" "Var1= 1" "Var1= 2" "Var1= 3" ...
  .. ..$ Var2: chr [1:31] "Var2= 0" "Var2= 1" "Var2= 2" "Var2= 3" ...
```

note that R is 1-indexed so `c(0:30)[1]` = `0`.